# Javascript - Finding distinct properties in array of objects (matrix)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, columnsorting

Background: Pre-processing code will run on a lot of data to extract the properties that needs to be shown on a chart. The chart is a parallel coordinates chart. It will run in browser.

Snippet: Extracts the properties that changed and the related category

My snippet outputs the answer correctly, but not efficiently

```js
var all = [
    {
      Dim_A: { v: '0', category: 'Window' },
      Dim_B: { v: '-1', category: 'Wall' },
      Dim_C: { v: '0', category: 'Wall' },
      Dim_D: { v: '0', category: 'Exterior Wall' }
    },
    {
      Dim_A: { v: '0', category: 'Window' },
      Dim_B: { v: '2', category: 'Wall' },
      Dim_C: { v: '1', category: 'Wall' },
      Dim_D: { v: '0', category: 'Exterior Wall' }
    },
    {
      Dim_A: { v: '0', category: 'Window' },
      Dim_B: { v: '-1', category: 'Wall' },
      Dim_C: { v: '0', category: 'Wall' }
    },
    {
      Dim_A: { v: '0', category: 'Window' },
      Dim_B: { v: '-1', category: 'Wall' },
      Dim_C: { v: '0', category: 'Wall' },
      Dim_E: { v: '0', category: 'Exterior Wall' }
    }
  ]

  if (all.length < 2) {
    throw 'need at least 2'
  }

  let distinctDims = new Map()
  for (let i = 0; i < all.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < all.length; j++) {
      if (i === j) {
        continue
      }
      let a = all[i]
      let b = all[j]
      for (let pa in a) {
        if (!a[pa] || !b[pa] || a[pa].v !== b[pa].v)
          distinctDims[pa] = { category: a[pa].category }
      }
      for (let pb in b) {
        if (!a[pb] || !b[pb] || a[pb].v !== b[pb].v)
          distinctDims[pb] = { category: b[pb].category }
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(distinctDims)
```

This outputs correctly. Looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: *"Also on CodePen"* Better yet, put your runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: *"Looking for an efficient way to prepare the data before displaying it on a comparative chart"* Prepare it **how**? What do you need to do to it? Are you saying that the code you've shown does the task correctly, but you think it's inefficient and want a better way?

Comment: @t-j-crowder - Yes does the job, but will be good for lots of data

Comment: what do you mean with *"Extracts the properties that changed"*? and what is in this case *"distinct"* meaning?

Comment: By _changed_ do we include properties that exist in one element and not in another? That seems to be the basis for including properties `Dim_D` and `Dim_E` in the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making an assumption that by *changed* we include properties that exist at one point and not at another. That seems to be the basis for including properties `Dim_D` and `Dim_E` in the changes. If my assumption is correct, a single loop is sufficient to find the changes. There are three possible cases for a change:

- a value changes from the original at `all[0]`
- a value exists in `all[0]` but ceases to exist later
- a value does not exist in `all[0]` but appears later

```js
if (all.length < 2) {
  throw 'need at least 2'
}

const prevDims = all[0]
const distinctDims = new Map()

for (let i = 1; i < all.length; i++) {
  const currentDims = all[i];

  for (const key in currentDims) {
    if (!distinctDims[key]) {
      // add to distinctDims either if value changed, or if it was not present previously 
      if (!prevDims[key] || currentDims[key].v !== prevDims[key].v) {
          distinctDims[key] = { 
            category: currentDims[key].category 
          }
      }
    }
  }


  // Check for dimensions that existed previously but not currently
  for (const key in prevDims) {
    if (!distinctDims[key] && !currentDims[key]) {
      distinctDims[key] = { category: prevDims[key].category }
      delete prevDims[key]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or that a property exist in both but value changed. Great!